# 3D SpaceNavigator recognized but doesn't move 3D objects

Tags: graphics3d

3DConnexion SpaceNavigator 3D mouse is recognized and updates its 6 axes and two button values in real time when I issue the command

```
ControllerInformation[]
```

but when I click on a 3D graphic and try to rotate it, the graphic doesn't move. (Clicking outside of the graphic, and then moving the controller causes the notebook window to scroll up down, and left right. I remember this used to work for 3D graphics back in version ~9, but I've only just tried again with it after a long while so this might be a more recent issue)

Given that `ControllerInformation[]` is being correctly updated, is there a  setting somewhere to tell Mathematica to use these values to change a 3D graphics orientation when it has focus?

[image]

Comment: I have never been able to get my 3DConnexion SpaceNavigator to behave other than what you mention. I'm not sure about this, but I think the 3DConnexion needs to add Mathematica support in their drivers. I would be interested in what other users have experienced.

Comment: I heard from Mathematica technical support that support for 3DConnexion devices was removed since 11.1  I asked if support could be reinstated for  manipulating 3DGraphics when such an item has focus. I am hoping this might be implemented some time.

Comment: Do you happen to know with they have reinstated support for the spacemouse?