# 3D mouse compatibility with Mathematica 12

Tags: graphics3d, compatibility

I am interested in a purchasing a 3D mouse to navigate 3d Mathematica graphics.  I am interested in the Spacemouse Wireless (by 3Dconnexion) found here:

https://3dconnexion.com/us/product/spacemouse-wireless/

I see an older version of the Spacemouse was compatible with an older version of Mathematica (shown briefly) in this video:

https://www.wolfram.com/broadcast/video.php?c=89&ob=title&o=ASC&v=590&p=15&&disp=grid

However, I have found little to no mention of anyone using a 3D mouse or any joystick controller for a few years.  And it look like Mathematica removed support for the Spacemouse a few years ago in Mathematica 11 according to this post:

[3D SpaceNavigator recognized but doesn't move 3D objects](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/159415/3d-spacenavigator-recognized-but-doesnt-move-3d-objects)

Is anyone successfully using the Spacemouse or any other 3D mouse in version 12? I'm open to joysticks if you have any suggestions.  However, I do think I would prefer one-handed control with 6 degrees of freedom the Spacemouse offers.